# Making an array of random ints

Tags: c#, arrays, random, int

What i try to to, is generate an array of random int values, where the random values are taken between a min and a max.

So far i came up with this code:

```
int Min = 0;
int Max = 20;

int[] test2 = new int[5];
Random randNum = new Random();
foreach (int value in test2)
{
    randNum.Next(Min, Max);
}
```

But its not fully working yet.
I think i might be missing just 1 line or something.
Can anyone help me out pushing me in the right direction ?

Comment: You're not actually assigning a value to your array each iteration.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You are never assigning the values inside the `test2` array. You have declared it but all the values will be 0. Here's how you could assign a random integer in the specified interval for each element of the array:

```
int Min = 0;
int Max = 20;

// this declares an integer array with 5 elements
// and initializes all of them to their default value
// which is zero
int[] test2 = new int[5]; 

Random randNum = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < test2.Length; i++)
{
    test2[i] = randNum.Next(Min, Max);
}
```

alternatively you could use LINQ:

```
int Min = 0;
int Max = 20;
Random randNum = new Random();
int[] test2 = Enumerable
    .Repeat(0, 5)
    .Select(i => randNum.Next(Min, Max))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: that first one gave me even more errors, and so far my knowledge of c# just is about 2 weeks back hehe. the second one works like a charm. thanx for that

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the random.next result to the currrent index of your array within the loop

Comment: You can't add to an array, that's a list.. and if you did it in a `foreach` loop, the collection would be modified while iterating.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still the wrong answer and a bad one: using `foreach` is to access an array's elements, you can't populate them that way

Comment: Ahh I totally ignored the foreach loop in the original question.